# How to parse XML String and retrieve char index of elements?

Tags: java, xml, string, parsing, indexing

As in the title, I am currently dealing with the need to parse an XML formatted String while being able to store information about the character index of the start of an element tag and the end of an element tag within the original String. I've looked at SAX and DOM and I can't seem to find anything that would provide me that data. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if helpful, but given that SAX is sequential, couldn't you keep a counter of characters? The only problem is that some whitespace might be ignored.

Comment: Where exactly would I keep the counter and how would I increment it? Can you elaborate a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at `Locator`, `DefaultHandler` and `SAXParser`. As an example which gives line number and column number:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    String xml = 
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<project \n"+ 
            ">\n"+
            "    <description>A description</description>\n"+
            "</project>\n";
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
    InputSource inps = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    DefaultHandler df = new XDefaultHandler();
    sp.parse(inps, df);
}

static class XDefaultHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    Locator l = null;

    @Override
    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {
        l = locator;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("element: " + qName);
        System.out.println("locator: " + l.getLineNumber() + "/" + l.getColumnNumber());
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
element: project
locator: 3/2
element: description
locator: 4/18
```

Override other methods in XDefaultHandler to receive calls for end of elements etc.

EDIT: (hit the button too early)

From the documentation of `Locator.getLineNumber()`:

> Return the line number where the current document event ends. Lines are delimited by line ends, which are defined in the XML specification.
>
> Warning: The return value from the method is intended only as an approximation for the sake of diagnostics; it is not intended to provide sufficient information to edit the character content of the original XML document. In some cases, these "line" numbers match what would be displayed as columns, and in others they may not match the source text due to internal entity expansion.
>
> The return value is an approximation of the line number in the document entity or external parsed entity where the markup triggering the event appears.

Comment: Since I will be seeking various sections of the document by index, line and column won't help in this case unfortunately.